# Disable multiple radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, radio-button

I have a question form with multiple yes/no radio buttons each with it's own textarea that should only be enabled whenever "No" is selected for that particular question. Problem is the setup up I'm using only works for one question because of matching classes. 
I haven't been able to come up with a nice way of making each radio button pair unique and only affect it's own textarea.

I'm using the counter variable to make different class names for each group but the script only affects .class1 I need to modify the script and would like some advice.

This is part of the view I'm using.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
        {
           <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => Model.Questions[i].AnswerSelected, true, new { @class = "class" + i, value = "yes" }) Yes
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => Model.Questions[i].AnswerSelected, false, new { @class = "class" + i, value = "no" }) No
                    </div>
                </td>          
            <td>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(p => Model.Questions[i].ActionToTake, new { id = "text1" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Bits of markup from inspect element

```
<div>
      <input checked="checked" class="class0" data-val="true" data-val-required="The AnswerSelected field is required." id="Questions_0__AnswerSelected" name="Questions[0].AnswerSelected" type="radio" value="True"> Yes
      <input class="class0" id="Questions_0__AnswerSelected" name="Questions[0].AnswerSelected" type="radio" value="False"> No
</div>
<div>
    <textarea class="text0" cols="20" id="text0" name="Questions[0].ActionToTake" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
    <div>
      <input checked="checked" class="class1" data-val="true" data-val-required="The AnswerSelected field is required." id="Questions_1__AnswerSelected" name="Questions[1].AnswerSelected" type="radio" value="True"> Yes
      <input class="class1" id="Questions_1__AnswerSelected" name="Questions[1].AnswerSelected" type="radio" value="False"> No
</div>
    <textarea class="text1" cols="20" id="text1" name="Questions[1].ActionToTake" rows="2"></textarea>
```

and this is the script I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".class1").change(function (e) {
    if ($(this).val() === 'True') {
        $("#text1").prop('readonly', true);
        $("#text1").css('background-color', '#EBEBE4');
    } else if ($(this).val() === 'False') {
        $("#text1").prop('readonly', false);
        $("#text1").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
    }
});
})
```

Is there a good way to approach this? If you need more detail let me know.

(I've asked this before but felt I wasn't being clear enough in the question)

[image: since i'm awful at explaining here's a picture]

Comment: That was meant to be .class1 sorry

Comment: Just a little idea, I think that a slightly better approach might be giving a common class to EVERY radio button (like ".radiogroup") and place the textarea INSIDE the same div as the radio button. In this way, you can listen to every single .radiogroup change event and take the first textarea inside the div.

Comment: Just an example snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/dsebwh7o/ taking your HTML and giving the same class to ALL the radio buttons and parsing the textarea inside the same div instead. To "trigger" the change, you can comfortly do the BITWISE XOR between the current textarea status and 1, which will return false if is true and true if is false. For the background, apply the same exact rule.

Comment: Yes that makes more sense, guess I'll need to use something else for layout instead of <table>

Comment: You can still use a table, just place the textarea inside the div instead and you're done ;)

Comment: Can't have them on different columns though

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can do something like

```
$(':radio').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('[class^="text"]').prop('readonly', $(this).val() === 'False');
});
```

But it would be better if you add some common class to your radio inputs, textareas and their common wrapper-parents. So you will be able to use selectors based on that classes but not tag names.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try.